# How to convert RTF file in ByteArrayInputStream to PDF file in JAVA?

Tags: java, rtf, export-to-pdf

I am having a problem in exporting PDF file, i have a RTF file in ByteArrayInputStream object, now, how can i export PDF file?
Code example please!
Thanks a lot

Comment: Checkout this example http://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/java-convert-a-file-to-byte-array-then-convert-byte-array-to-a-file/

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a converter - something that will convert RTF to PDF.  It is not really relevant that you have a ByteArrayInputStream or that you want a file - they are minor technicalities compared to the converter you need.
Java doesn't such a facility built in so you need a library etc.  JODConverter might help you if you need a free library.